# Replacing splash screen and license text after installer generation - Supporting Rebranding

Tags: install4j

What strategies have your tried when designing installers capable of rebranding?  For OEM etc, I may want the customer to be able to replace license text, splash screen images etc but use my stock installer so we know we have the same binaries and installer logic.

I imagine I can achieve this through on of the following:

- externalize license text, splash screens etc and ship installer in a zip with an executable and a configuration directory containing these file.
- break installer into merged modules and ship as a zip with an executable install and replaceable merge modules (the OEM partner would need to purchase install4j to build their merge modules)

Please let me know if you've found a strategy for customized installers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my installer could run in quiet mode and I my product included a rebranding tool then I could do something like this:

my installer contains the following:

- application
- application/resourceFiles (including license)
- application/util/rebrander.jar

OEM partner creates its own installer which

- runs my unmodified installer in quiet / unattended mode
- deposits its own rebrandingFiles
- runsRebrander to update application/resourceFiles with its content
- handles failure cases

This means my installer is unmodified so no issues with signing.  Partner's installer is up to them to handle.  Not sure how to handle uninstall cleanly since the user could see and uninstall my installer from add-Remove programs.

Comment: You don't have to create an "Add/Remove" entry, just delete the "Register Add/Remove item" action from your installer.

Answer (score 0):

While it would be possible in principle to do this with external data files, they cannot be shipped efficiently. Most importantly that strategy would not work for downloading.

Changing the installer later on is not possible due to the signature. If anything in the installer is changed, it would have to be signed again. You cannot hand out your private key of your code signing certificate to your partners, so everybody needs their own code-signing certificate.

So the only possiblity for rebranding is to use the install4j compiler to recompile the installers.

Comment: Thanks Ingo,  I guess I could let the vendor encapsulate my installer in their own, running mine in unattended mode.  If both they and I use install4j then it should be easier than if they use something else. (see the other answer).